# php formatting new lines and spacing

Tags: php, replace, teamspeak

This is a little complicated to explain but I'll try my hardest, I'm trying to create a tool to edit channel descriptions for TeamSpeak 3, to do this you use a feature called channeledit.

example usage: channeledit channel_description=My\sDescription

Presumably \s = space \n = newline, is there any possible way from using a textarea to php script to have it output the line as:

My\sDescription\nWelcome\sto\smy\sServer

Rather than appearing as:
My Description
Welcome to my Server

If there is spacing or line breaks, this kills the command and stops it working. Can anyone give me a bit of help here?

Code for this is:

$name = "Test
Test
Test test test";

$ts3_VirtualServer->execute("channeledit cid=" . $current_cid . " channel_description=" . $name);

Comment: After testing it's handling spaces fine, just new lines cause it to break.. not sure why though.

Comment: Please try: `$name = str_replace("\r","\\n",$name);`

Comment: It errors with: test\n test

Comment: So the teamspeak 3 framework probably does not want to handle the \  have you just tried passing `urlencode($name)` to it??

Comment: urlencode makes it appear like: Testing+Space%0D%0ANew+Line in the channel, it sets the description do to the fact it creates a full line with now spaces

Comment: one more thing I would try, is just changing the standard RC with a NL, like : `$name = str_replace("\r","\n",$name);`  If that does not work, go visit the github for the TS3 framework, and see how `channeledit` is handling the string.

Comment: aha! I seem to have gotten it working by doing this: $name = urlencode($name);
$name = str_replace("+","\s",$name);
$name = str_replace("%0D%0A",'\n',$name);
$name = urldecode($name);

Comment: Thanks for helping me get there!

Answer (score 0):

$name=STR_replace(" ","/s",$name) 
    $name= str_replace("\n", '\n', $name);

Comment: Doesn't work with new lines though. I can get spaces to work fine, just not new lines.

Comment: Ok then $name= str_replace("\n", '\n', $name);   pay attention to single and double quotation

Comment: theres a space after 1 .R u sure that u take care of spaces?

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = "Test Test
Test test test";
(string)$newname = str_replace(' ', '\\s', $name);
$newname = urldecode(str_replace('%0A', "\\n", urlencode($newname)));
```

You need to escape (\) the backslash (\). %0A 's are easier to find.
My output:

Test\sTest\nTest\stest\stest

Comment: For some reason it doesn't seem to like the new lines: Test \n\sTestTest\stest\stest

Comment: With hardcoding the value to test test etc.. it works, but when input from the text editor it does not work.

Comment: That's why I used the urlencode; to change the original \n's to %0A. It took the $_GET data and made sure it was encoded.  Let me play with it, be back in a minute or two.

Comment: Yeah, but for some reason it wont work when I use a new line in the text area from the form on the html page before.

Comment: Search for %0D%0A after the encode for you newline substitute. It gets rid of the mysterious space, but my original code still works. Locale probably. To clarify:`urldecode(str_replace('%0D%0A', "\\n", urlencode($newname)));`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace spaces and carriage returns with literal `\n` and `\s`. I would do the following:

```
$name = urldecode(str_replace("%0D%0A","\\n",str_replace("+","\\s",urlencode($name))));
```